# Project.Build does not work with DeployOnBuild=true

Tags: msbuild, microsoft.build

My code is as follows:

```
...

propertyGroup1.AddProperty("DeployOnBuild", "true");
propertyGroup1.AddProperty("DeployTarget", "MSDeployPublish");
propertyGroup1.AddProperty("MSDeployServiceUrl", "localhost");
propertyGroup1.AddProperty("DeployIisAppPath", "local.projects.com");
propertyGroup1.AddProperty("MSDeployPublishMethod", "InProc");
propertyGroup1.AddProperty("AllowUntrustedCertificate", "true");

...

cSharpProject.ProjectCollection.RegisterLogger(cSharpLogger);
try {
      buildResult = cSharpProject.Build();
...
```

`buildResult` is set to `false`. However, it does **not** raise any error to the logger. And the project is **not** deployed.

I'm running my exe in Administrator mode.

Any help is apprecited.

Thanks

Chris
*hint*: `CSAutoParameterize.parameters` and other subfolders have not been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      <Target Name="WebPublish">
    <MsBuild Projects="MyProject.csproj" Properties="DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;MSDeployServiceUrl=localhost;DeployIisAppPath=local.website.com;MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;AllowUntrustedCertificate=true;Username=someuser;password=somepassword" />
  </Target>
```

I was able to add this target to the project and call just that specific target.